# Getting waypoints between 2 gps coordinates from cities table

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, gps, coordinates

How could I retrieve a list of cities which are enroute(waypoints) between 2 gps coordinates?

I have a table of all cities, lat-lon.
So if I have a starting location (lat-lon) and ending location (lat-lon)...
It must be very easy to determine the path of cities (from table) to pass by(waypoints) to get from start(lat-lon) to en (lat-lon)?

I have looked different algorithms and bearing. Still not clear for me.

Comment: Does your cities table include linkage data? e.g. "city A to city B, take road #57"? Locations by themselves are useless unless you've got data on how they interconnect. Otherwise the simple answer is "drive directly between Start and Ending points"

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the between point A and B method, then you'd just query the cities with Latitude and Longitude between the first and the second, respectively.

If you want to get the cities that are within X miles of a straight line from A to B, then you'd calculate the starting point and slope, and then query cities which are within X miles of the line that creates

If you're not using a simple point A to point B method which ignores roads, then you'll need some kind of data on the actual roads between A and B for us to give you an answer.  This can be done using a Node system in your db, and it can also be done by using various geolocation APIs that are out there.

Answer (score 1):

the solution to this can be found by standard discrete routing algorithms

those algorithms need a set of nodes (start, destination, your cities) and edges between those nodes (representing the possible roads or more generally the distances between the locations.)

nodes and edges form a graph ... start point and destination are known ... now you can use algorithms like A* or djikstra to solve a route along this graph

a typical problem for this approach could be that you don't have definitions for the edges (the usable direct paths between locations). you could create such a "road network" in various ways, for example:

initialize "Network_ID" with 0

take your starting location, and find the closest other location. measure the distance and multiply it by a factor. now connect each location to the original location which has a distance less than this value and is not connected to the current location yet. add all locations that were connected by this step to a list. mark the current location with the current "Network_ID" repeat this step for the next location on that list. if your list runs out of locations, increment "Network_ID" and choose a random location that has not yet been processed and repeat the step

after all locations have been processed you have one or more road networks (if more than one, they are not connected yet. add a suitable connection edge between them, or restart the process with a greater factor)

you have to make sure, that either start and destination have the same network_ID or that both networks have been connected

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...  I have used BETWEEN min AND max for something like this, but not quite the same.
try maybe:

```
SELECT * from `cities` WHERE `lat` BETWEEN 'minlat' AND 'maxlat' AND `lon` BETWEEN 'minlon' and 'maxlon';
```

something like that may work

look at mysql comparisons here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but if you are still working on this problem you should read this:-
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html